# JPA - saving objects together

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I've an Entity (javax.persistence) object with three fields - A, B and deleted. The combination (A, B, deleted) should be unique. I'm using true/null as the values for deleted so that the unique constraint holds good in MySQL.

Let's assume I already have a record in the db (1, a1, b1, true). Now I'm trying to update deleted to null for that record and at the same time insert a new object (2, a1, b1, true). So that, my table looks at the end of the transaction as (1, a1, b1, null), (2, a1, b1, true). However, this code fails with the unique constraint violation. I understand this as the expected behavior because until the transaction is committed, the existing record will trigger the violation exceptions.

Are there any ways to do what I want and not have the exception thrown?

Pseudo code:

The whole thing is in a method marked Transactional.

`dbObj = repo.find(..) // returns (1, a1, b1, true)
newObj = copyFrom(dbObj) // creates another (a1, b1, true)
dbObj.setValid(null)
repo.save(dbObj)
repo.save(newObj)`

Comment: you can check before if given record exists by performing a query

Comment: Updated with some code. I know that there is an existing record. I'm trying to mark that deleted and create a new one (biz reasons) with the same value for the key columns A and B.

Comment: Call `entityManager.flush()` before saving the new object. Or make the unique constraint deferred, i.e. only checked at commit time (if MySQL supports deferred constraints). Note that calling save() on a managed entity is useless. A managed object state is saved automatically.

Comment: yo should do the modifications in two separate transactions

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather advise you to follow the steps in below pseudo code to achieve this.

1) Define default value for valid indicator column value as false.

```
private void saveObject(){
  dbObj = repo.find(..) 
  EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
  EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
  dbObj.setValid(false);
  tx.persist(dbObj);
  em.flush();

  newObj(a1,b1,true);
  tx.persist(newObj);
  em.flush();

tx.commit();
}
```